# X labels gets cut out for faceted ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I formatted facet_wrap so that its lables will be on the at the plot bottom instead of on top of the plot (see pic attached).
When the faceted label is too long, it get's cut out of the facet borders.
How can I override this to allow longer strings to be in front of the facet graph?

In the attached plot the second facet label (which is 'really_really_really_long_lable_here') gets cut.

I can change figure dimensions and text size but the optimal solution for me is to arrange the facet strip text to be in front of the figure itself and therefore to allow long strings to appear in full length.

Dataframe to recreate this example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(seq(1:10)), b = seq(1:10), group = c(rep('group1',5), rep('really_really_really_long_lable_here',5)), 
                 sex = c(rep(c('M','F'),5)))


ggplot(df, aes(sex,b, group = sex)) +
              geom_boxplot() +
              facet_wrap(~group, strip.position = "bottom") +
              theme(strip.placement = "outside",
                    strip.background = element_blank(),
                    text = element_text(size = 16)) +
              xlab(NULL)
```

[example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMwZ0.png)

Comment: By "in front of the facet graph", do you mean along the left edge? For that, I'd go with `strip.position="left"`.

Comment: In the dev version of ggplot, you can set `theme(strip.clip = "off")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. I'll save your plot as `p` to demonstrate:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  a = seq(1:10), 
  b = seq(1:10), 
  group = c(rep('group1', 5), rep('really_really_really_long_lable_here', 5)), 
  sex = c(rep(c('M', 'F'), 5))
)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(sex, b, group = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~group, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16)) +
  xlab(NULL)
```

#### 1. Change your facet layout:

```
p +
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, strip.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

#### 2. Change the font size:

```
p +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 6))
```

[image]

#### 3. Use text wrapping:

```
# Wrapping function that replaces underscores with spaces
wrap_text <- function(x, chars = 10) {
  x <- gsub("_", " ", x)
  stringr::str_wrap(x, chars)
}

# Alternative wrapping function that just drops a linebreak in every 10
# chars
wrap_text2 <- function(x, chars = 10) {
  regex <- sprintf("(.{%s})", chars)
  gsub(regex, "\\1\n", x)
}

p +
  facet_wrap(
    ~group, strip.position = "bottom",
    labeller = as_labeller(wrap_text)
  )
```

[image]

#### 4. Use `strip.clip`

As of July 2022, the (unreleased) development version of `ggplot2` includes a `strip.clip` argument to `theme()`. Setting this to `"off"` means the strip text will be layered *on top* of the panel like so:

```
p +
  theme(strip.clip = "off")
```

[image]

Note: you can get the development version of `ggplot2` using `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`. Or you can wait a few months for the next version to arrive on CRAN.

My favourite approach is #3 - or to just use shorter labels!

Comment: Thanks wurli. Yes, I know these options but I am looking for more robust solution. Is there even a way of increasing each facet width size?

Comment: There's no way to change the facet width size based on the length of each label. The closest thing you'll get is to simply save the plot with a larger size. For this, you can check out the `dpi`, `width` and `height` arguments to `ggsave()`

Comment: Actually there's a feature in the development version of ggplot2 which you might also find useful. I'll make an edit to my solution...

Comment: Edit now made. If you're willing to use the development version of ggplot2 this might be your preferred solution seeing as it's (I think) exactly what you asked for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_wrap` from `{stringr}` package to handle long labels in plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)


df <- data.frame(a = c(seq(1:10)), b = seq(1:10), 
                 group = c(rep('group1',5), rep('really_really_really_long_lable_here',5)), 
                 sex = c(rep(c('M','F'),5)))


wrap_label <- function(x) str_wrap(str_replace_all(x, "_", " "), width = 20)

ggplot(df, aes(sex,b, group = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~group, strip.position = "bottom", labeller = as_labeller(wrap_label)) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16)) +
  xlab(NULL)
```

[image: plot with multiline label for facet]